# emulator throwing hostunresolved exception in android?

Tags: android

i have as my first activity in my application a request to a certain address, from where i get XML and then i parse it...
I have added the permission on for internet access in my android.manifest file.

**my problem**

whenever i run my application on my emulator the following exception is thrown:

```
05-19 18:25:05.099: WARN/System.err(473): java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: www.svgverlag.de:80
```

i don't understand what is going wrong.

*when i open the same address in my browser it opens up fine*

i have tried restarting the emulator several times.
i am using a mac.

thank you in advance.

EDIT:

i have tried creating several emulators and in all of them this is happening.Also i tried on my friends macbook pro, and the same thing is happening.
Also in the emulator's browser no webpage is opening.For some reason the emulator is not able to access the internet.

**UPDATE**

I believe that there is a problem with the emulator on mac per se. No matter what i try:

set the dns in Eclipse Preferences using dns-server- 8.8.8.8

turn of my firewall

nothing seems to make a difference and my emulator is not able to access the internet.

Also there is a 3G symbol at the top of my emulator but with no help regarding internet access.
While on a my windows machine, things seem to work fine without any settings from my side.

what do i do?

Comment: By browser you mean to say in android browser?

Comment: open your emulator browser and check internet is working or not.

Comment: i was talking about my computer browser.

Comment: also i tried it on mobile browser .... and it is giving webpage not found.. so in other words, the same thing is happening on device browser? what is going wrong with the emulator?

Comment: i tried to make a new emulator and tried the same on it but the same thing is happening. i am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the IP address of this website instead of using its host name?

Comment: nopes. i can't i gotta use the hostname. Also in my friends emulator on windows the thing is working fine. what is going wrong over here?

Comment: when i open the same address in my browser it opens up fine - You meant the emulators browser or your PC browser? If its a PC browser cross check it on your emulators browser as well. btw can you check whether you are able to see a 3g icon on the top of android notification bar. If the issue persists try creating a new AVD

Comment: i meant the computer browser, but i tried it on the emulator browser.. and it is not opening the any website.. so there is some problem with the emulator. i will try creating a new emulator.

Comment: Accessing website using host name always gives this type of error, but if we use use IP address then it works fine.Is there any solution for it?

Comment: i tried to make a new emulator and tried the same on it but the same thing is happening.i am getting the same error.

Comment: @user590849 can you clarify if _you_ are able to access a web site from within the browser by numeric IP, or even ping an internet host by numeric IP from the adb shell command line?

Comment: i have not tried either. i am directly using hostname. i have tried to access the internet from the mobile's browser but that does not work.